# WP Multisite Child Site Redirecting to main site when not HTTPs

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a multi-site WP installation. The main site is at https://main-site.com

I have a child site https://child.org. The child site loads fine in the following variations:

1. https://www.child.org
2. https://child.org

I'm trying to setup a redirect so that whenever a user tries to navigate to the site in HTTP, that it redirects to HTTPS. **I've tried a lot of rules but all of them always redirect the HTTP child site to the HTTPS main site**. After spending a long time working with the file I've come to realize that %{HTTP_HOST} is always the main site. I've also tried using %{SERVER_NAME} with the same result.

My WP multisite installation is in /var/www/html

My /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf contains the following:

```
# Added to mitigate CVE-2017-8295 vulnerability
UseCanonicalName On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        
        ServerName $domain
        ServerAlias www.$domain
        
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

How can I update this so that %{HTTP_HOST} is the domain that the user entered into the request? Or is there another variable I can use instead of %{HTTP_HOST} and %{SERVER_NAME} that will contain the correct domain? Currently those variables always return main-site.com

EDIT 1: Found this cheatsheet for .htaccess variables https://gist.github.com/fmtarif/968eaa25e165c59b21d5

I don't see any other variables that can give me what I'm looking for (the domain the user typed in), it looks like there is something wrong with the way my multi-site is setup which might be causing this.

Edit 2: Here's some additional info which may be the root of the problem. I am using this domain mapping plugin for WP multisites.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

The instructions in the domain mapping plugin page (in the WP backend) say "If you want to redirect a domain you will need to add a DNS "A" record pointing at the IP address of this server: {INSERT  SERVER IP BELONGING TO main-site.com}"

So in the hosting networking, I added an A name for child.org to be {INSERT  SERVER IP BELONGING TO main-site.com}. I suppose the reason HTTP_HOST is main-site.com instead of child.org is because the change is happening at the DNS level? But how does the plugin work properly when using HTTPS?

EDIT 3: When I type in https://child.org then the %{HTTP_HOST} variable is the correct child.org instead of main-site.com, but when I type in http://child.org it is main-site.com.

EDIT 4:
This is the MU Domain Mapping network site configuration
[image]

This is the child site MU Domain mapping configuration
[image]

EDIT 5:
I think the root of the issue may be the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

This site only specifies the main-site.com domain. So this may be the reason why regardless of what I enter into the URL, the %{HTTP_HOST} is always `main-site.com`. Here is what is in that file.

```
# Added to mitigate CVE-2017-8295 vulnerability
UseCanonicalName On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        
        ServerName main-site.com
        ServerAlias www.main-site.com
        
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =main-site.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.main-site.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT 6:
These are the contents of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        
        ServerName $domain.com
        ServerAlias www.$domain.com
        
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias child.main-site.com
ServerAlias child.org
ServerAlias child2.main-site.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/child.main-site.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/child.main-site.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: _"How can I update this so that %{HTTP_HOST} is the domain that the user entered into the request?"_ - that _should_ be the case, unless your setup involves proxying requests or something like that - which I currently don't see any indication of. What _exactly_ is your setup for that child.org virtual host?

Comment: I added some more info in EDIT 2, let me know if that helps

Comment: The DNS A record only resolves the child.org host name to an IP address, nothing more. Any client requesting `http://child.org/...`, will still send `child.org` in the HOST request header. If `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains anything other than that, then it must have been altered somewhere, after the request left the client - some sort of proxy, load balancer, etc.

Comment: _'The instructions in the domain mapping plugin page (in the WP backend) say "If you want to redirect a domain [...]'_ - not sure how a _redirect_ actually comes into play here - you don't want to redirect child.org anywhere else, you want it to show a specific WP site. May the settings made in that plugin have something to do with the issue, can you share details of what exactly is configured there?

Comment: The RewriteConds before `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}.org [R=307,L]` are currently commented in the .htaccess you have shown above, is that really the case? If you _are_ performing this redirect, then `SERVER_NAME` would likely be the wrong variable to use, because that presumably _is_ actually main-site.com.And with this external redirect, you should see the browser address bar also say `main-site.com` afterwards. And when the browser makes that request, of course HTTP_HOST will contain that value as well.

Comment: Either use `%{HTTP_HOST}` in that redirect; or, if you want to get rid of a `www.` prefix at this point as well - _capture_ the hostname part after an (optional) `www.` in the RewriteCond, and use the back reference in the RewriteRule.

Comment: I've updated the EDIT 4 to include the configuration at the network site level and child site level. I also updated my DNS settings of child.org (removed the A name in child.org from pointing to the IP address of main-site.com) and created a CNAME from www.child.org to platform.main-site.com.

In the main-site.com DNS settings I added a CNAME from platform.main-site.com to main-site.com

Comment: Those rules were made just to test whether or not my HTACCESS was working. The rules which IMO should work are:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

However, that always redirects back to the main-site.com in HTTPS. Instead of staying on the child site.

Comment: Weird thing is also that when I enter `http://child.org` or `http://www.child.org` in the brave browser it works fine. But in firefox it redirects the http version to the https main-site.com. In that same vein, if I go to a site screen shotter and I enter the http versions above, it also shows me a picture of the https main-site.com (meaning it redirected to main-site.com) so I think my brave browser is simply "correcting" my lack of https, and the redirect at the DNS/server level is still wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify what your .htaccess now actually contains? (You can't have that first redirect in there now without any conditions, I suppose, that should land you in a redirect loop.)

Comment: Updated .htaccess to reflect what it contains and also added EDIT 5 which contains /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf. I think this file is the reason why %{HTTP_HOST} is always main-site.com even when I type http://child.org in the URL bar.

Comment: Those `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}` make little sense - SERVER_NAME will always be the value you _specified_ with `ServerName main-site.com`, it does not come from the request. And if `http://child.org` routes into that same virtual host, then of course it will go wrong at this point.

Comment: Please refresh the page, it should have the correct .htaccess file now

Comment: I think your VirtualHost config should contain only `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]`, without any additional conditions. All you want to do there, is redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. So don't _change_ the host name there by using `%{SERVER_NAME}`, but keep the actual requested host name, `%{HTTP_HOST}`. (Or, if you want to get rid of a `www.` prefix as well at that point, use a RewriteCond to "extract" only the part of that, from the request host name.)

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and tried that - replaced the condition and rule with `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]` but it ended up in an endless redirect. It still redirected from `http://child.org` to `https://main-site.com` but then it continued trying to redirect to `https://main-site.com` endlessly.

Comment: _"t still redirected from `http://child.org` to `https://main-site.com`"_ - probably the result of a _cached_ redirect; please make sure you test this in a private browser window. _"but then it continued trying to redirect to `https://main-site.com` endlessly"_ - that last part can't be happening based on your redirecting in the virtual host - the vhost is set to listen on port 80 only, so as soon as you redirected to HTTPS, anything in there doesn't apply any more to the following requests.

Comment: I did try to cache bust the URL with query params such as `?33` and `?34` etc. I do this everytime I update the .htaccess file. I also tried it in firefox and in incognito but it is redirecting endlessly. I added EDIT 6 which contains the contents of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf

Comment: Enable a bit of rewrite logging, then you can see in detail what happens.